# How to make some links in nav to not hide on mobile? bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a 2 li dropdowns in the nav menu on bootstrap. I want the first to hide, and the second not to. But by default bootstrap hides all lists under the burger icon on small screens.

I am using pure bootstrap 3 code from there site:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">NOT HIDE ON MOBILE <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!-- HOW TO MAKE THIS PART NOT HIDE ON MOBILE? -->

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Sorry, added. I am using pure bootstrap 3 code from there site

Answer (score 0):

In this case you'd have to add some custom CSS media queries to position the navbar components accordingly.

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/5E3YxlDKYy

```
/* float the left and right collapsible navs only on desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .pull-sm-left {
       float:left;
    }

    .pull-sm-right {
       float:right;
    }
}

/* absolute position the single item next to the brand on mobile */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-text.list-inline {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 100px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can put it after `navbar-brand` inside `navbar-header` div as:

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
 <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="#">Menu</a>
```

You can use button or drop downs there
Hope this helps..